# 2006 Mustang GT: Left car for 1 week, no power when returning

Tags: ford, battery, power, mustang

I went on vacation for a week. The car was working fine before I left.

I came back and there is no power. Can't turn on headlights or unlock/lock with remote, and the car gives a clicking sound when starting. Tried booster cables and also wall charger for battery, and the wall charger says the battery is 80%+ charged. 
I didn't leave the headlights or interior lights on either so somehow it magically got disconnected or blew a fuse it seems.

any ideas?

car: 2006 Mustang GT Convertible

Comment: Have you tried push-starting the car?

Comment: @JuannStrauss I believe that push-starting can damage catalytic converters. At least in my 2003 Volvo S60 owners manual it states: `"If the car's battery is dead, do not attempt to start the vehicle by pushing or pulling it as this will damage
the three-way catalytic converter(ss). The engine must be jump started using an auxiliary battery"`

Comment: So much for progress then.

Answer (score 7):

How old is the battery?  If it's the original one, it's probably just in need of replacement.  5-7 years is a typical battery lifetime.  At the end of life, they will sometimes appear to charge, but die rapidly if not used for a few days.

Comment: You can have the battery tested for free at a parts store or some battery chargers have testers built in.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it was the battery after all.. the charger I was using gave a false positive for being charged possible because it was connected to a slightly rusted bolt for grounding.

The cables I was using were also slightly rusted,  I bought new ones and after fiddling a few times we we able to jumpstart it.